# Is it legal to use a static fragment inside another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it legal to use a static fragment inside another fragment. 
I just want to reuse an old fragment and add some design to it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000" >


    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="com.example.android.camera2video.Camera2VideoFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/camera_fragment">
    </fragment>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello from another fragment"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried it before asking the question?

Comment: Yes I tested it and it works , I just want to know if that's a bad practice or no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.  Now doing a transaction and replacing a nested fragment has some issues.

Comment: `has some issues` Always be specific. For example, transactions with inflated fragments are straight up not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do this. It is explicitly called out as something that won't work in the documentation about nested Fragments:

`Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a <fragment>. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.`

See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Create a container to hold that `Fragment` instead and add it programmatically using the parent `Frament`'s `FragmentManager` returned by `getChildFragmentManager`.

Comment: The article is about platform fragments from version 4.2. It may be outdated. Platform fragment implementation evolves and the support library keeps up.

Comment: Sure that's a good point. I'm pretty sure this hasn't changed since then, though.